# не судите строго , объясните пошагово - что здесь написано?

Tags: css, инспекция-кода

```
.gallery {
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px grey;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    min-height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: centre; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прямо совсем пошагово?

1. Видим блок с классом "gallery", это может быть секция галереи на сайте.
2. Добавляем свойство box-shadow со значением "5px 5px 10px grey", это свойство добавляет тень вокруг блока с галереей.
3. Добавляем свойство padding со значением "20px", это свойство добавляет внутренний отступ вокруг контента блока.
4. Добавляем свойство margin-bottom со значением "20px", это свойство добавляет нижний внешний отступ для блока.
5. Добавляем свойство min-height со значением "300px", это свойство задает минимальную высоту для блока.
6. Добавляем свойство display со значением "flex", это свойство позволяет дочерним элементам блока корректно располагаться внутри родителя.
7. Добавляем свойство align-items со значением "center", это свойство выравнивает дочерние элементы по вертикали в центре блока